# Concatenate a string while populating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

Here is my code to populate albums and their images :

```
server.get(url_prefix + '/image', function(req, res, next) {
        var album_id = req.query.album_id
        Album.findOne(
                {_id : album_id}
             )
             .populate('images')
             .exec(function (err, album) {
                if (album) {
                    return res.send({
                        status: {
                            error: 0,
                            message: "Successful"
                        },
                        data: {
                            album: album
                        }
                    })
                } else
                    return notify_error(res, "No Results", 1, 404)
             })


    })
```

Album schema :

```
var AlbumSchema = new Schema(
{
    userId:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    albumName:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    albumDescription:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    imageCount:{ 
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    timestamp:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    albumThumbnail:{ 
        type: Object
    }, 
    images : [{ 
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                ref: 'Image' 
              }
    ]
})
```

Image schema :

```
var ImageSchema = new Schema(
{
    _album : { type: String, ref: 'Album' },
    imageName:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    imageDescription:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    timestamp:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    imageURL:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    imageURLSmall:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    imageThumbnailURL:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    likeCount:{ 
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    commentCount:{ 
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    userLike:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})
```

I am able to populate the albums and their images, In image schema `imageURL` contains only the image name (`image.jpg`) so while retrieving I want it to be like `http://localhost/assets/profile/image.jpg` I have to do it while populating the data or before sending the data, because this API s are used by mobile devices so they need the full path to show the image.

So how can I add a string to a field in mongodb while populating the data ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you only storing the name of the image in the imageUrl field? Can you not store the full url of the image in there at creation time?

Comment: @AlistairNelson : Is that a good idea? This is how I was practicing from the beginning. It will be helpful in case we need to change the server. But I guess in any programming they are not saving the complete path of the image.

Comment: Another place where you could do what you want to do is within the .exec(function (err, album) {
                if (album) { part as here you have all the data you need, you could then manipulate your urls in here before you send it down to the client

Comment: @AlistairNelson : Thanks for that suggestion, but the problem is, before completing loop it sends the response (code after loop is executed before loop is completed),so i manually need to check if the loop is completed, this becomes code complicated and unprofessional. So I am looking for some proper way of doing it.

Comment: What loop? If you update your data before you return the response, then you will be able to do whatever you want before the response is sent. Once you have this working you can work on making it better in terms of doing it the proper way...

Comment: @AlistairNelson : Images are array inside album object, so I need to change the URL of all the images, So I guess I need to do it in loop, or I am doing it in a wrong way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ImageSchema
    .post('init', function(obj) {
        var url = 'http://localhost/assets/profile/'
        obj.imageURL = url + obj.imageURL
    })
```

This function will be executed every time you grab an object from the database.